# Vector literal in JAGS/WinBUGS

Tags: r, winbugs, jags

Is there any way how to write a vector literal in JAGS/WinBUGS? I tried these in JAGS, all result in an error:

```
pi <- [p*q, p*(1-q)*q, p*pow(1-q,2)*q, p*pow(1-q,3)*q]
pi <- (p*q, p*(1-q)*q, p*pow(1-q,2)*q, p*pow(1-q,3)*q)
pi <- c(p*q, p*(1-q)*q, p*pow(1-q,2)*q, p*pow(1-q,3)*q)
```

I don't want to assign them one by one.

Haven't actually find anything useful [here](http://jeromyanglim.tumblr.com/post/37362208383/how-to-assign-a-vector-to-a-variable-in-jags) or in the manual.

Comment: Pretty sure this is not possible. See also Martyn's comment [here](http://sourceforge.net/p/mcmc-jags/discussion/610036/thread/e9f67264/#289c).